# SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[portal]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.wps.cei.DebugController

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, portal, websphere-portal

Tried all the possible ways to resolve the below error on WAS console failing to start the WebSphere Portal server with the below:

> Could not display the portlet, an exception has occurred. User action: Check the server logs, there will be a warning message associated with this error of the form " while rendering a page...", this message will contain more detail of the error. Mostly likely cause is the console module has been uninstalled.

Below is the exception
SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[portal]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.wps.cei.DebugController

This occurred while I was trying to install .war into themes.

Kindly help to get a path forward to resolve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check those logs?

Comment: Hello James.. Thanks for your response . Verified the logs and it throws  Asynchronous work load with Websphere Application Server

Comment: I was trying to install .war into there int portal configuration and after restarting the portal server , not able to start and throwing the title exception as above and a synchronous exception

Comment: "it throws Asynchronous work load" is not enough information to help you debug this, pls update your question with the contents of the exception from SystemOut.log/SystemErr.log/FFDCs.

Comment: Hello Rowe.. Thanks for your response, Below is the exception in the logs:                                                                                                    E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[portal]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.wps.cei.DebugController

Comment: SCHD0063E: A task with ID 401 (wcm#WCM_EJBs.jar#EJBScheduler) failed to run on Scheduler WPSTaskScheduler (wps/Scheduler) because of an exception: com.ibm.ejs.container.UnknownLocalException: nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.wps.services.workmanager.WorkException: EJPFD0031E: An error has occurred in the AsynchBeans layer of WebSphere Application Server..

Comment: Any help would be appreciated, I'm struck with this since a day and not moving forward, tried all the possible ways, Kindly help

Comment: Rowe, can you please advice me if possible

Comment: I've noticed that PA_WCMLRingPortJSR286 failed to start, Is that something I need to check for the above exceptions, I tried to start that in WAS console but it give the below error:    ErrorPA_WCMLRingPortJSR286 failed to start. Check the logs for server WebSphere_Portal on node XXXXXNode for details.
ErrorAn error occurred while starting PA_WCMLRingPortJSR286. Check the logs for server WebSphere_Portal on node XXXXNode for more information.